# Remove element from 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's assume I have 3d numpy array as follows:

```
arr = np.ndarray(shape = (3,3,3), dtype=np.float32)


array([[[2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38]],

   [[2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38]],

   [[2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38]]], dtype=float32)
```

I want to able to delete the arbitrary row from this array. For instance, If I want to delete the first row, I want to get the following array:

```
array([[[2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38]],

   [[2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38],
    [2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38, 2.3694278e-38]]], dtype=float32)
```

But this question is not just about to delete the first row. I want able to delete the row which I want. I tried `np.delete()` function but could not get exactly what I want. Could someone show how it is possible to do it?

Comment: What have you tried with `np.delete` and what it's missing compared to your ecpectations?

Comment: What about `np.delete(arr, 1, 0)`?

Comment: `arr = arr[1:,:,:]`

Comment: Read the https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Comment: Sorry It is my mistake, It is (3,3,3) shaped array

Comment: Note that np.delete returns a copy of arr. It doesn't delete from arr.

Comment: I tried np.delete(a, 0, axis=1) but It just delete the first row in each 2d array

Comment: To create a reproducible sample, use something like : `arr = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)`. That way users can have a better understanding on the required operation.

Answer (score 8):

You can try:

```
x = np.delete(arr, 0, axis=0)
```

**first Array (arr):**

```
   [[[-3.5406988e-10  4.5735579e-41  4.8186282e-38]
  [ 0.0000000e+00 -2.4307778e-10  4.5735579e-41]
  [-2.2672175e-10  4.5735579e-41 -5.2388177e-11]]

 [[ 4.5735579e-41 -1.2597114e-09  4.5735579e-41]
  [-1.2705312e-09  4.5735579e-41 -2.1648838e-10]
  [ 4.5735579e-41 -2.4543772e-19  4.5735579e-41]]

 [[-2.4543917e-19  4.5735579e-41 -6.6015360e-11]
  [ 4.5735579e-41 -2.4544351e-19  4.5735579e-41]
  [-2.4199687e-10  4.5735579e-41 -1.2076065e-09]]]
```

**new Array(x):**

```
[[[ 4.5735579e-41 -1.2597114e-09  4.5735579e-41]
  [-1.2705312e-09  4.5735579e-41 -2.1648838e-10]
  [ 4.5735579e-41 -2.4543772e-19  4.5735579e-41]]

 [[-2.4543917e-19  4.5735579e-41 -6.6015360e-11]
  [ 4.5735579e-41 -2.4544351e-19  4.5735579e-41]
  [-2.4199687e-10  4.5735579e-41 -1.2076065e-09]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Do not use `np.delete`

`np.delete` creates a copy, often unnecessarily. Instead, use [basic slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to return a view. If you only provide one slice, then only the first dimension will be sliced.

```
arr_sliced = arr[1:]
```

You can create a copy explicitly if you wish:

```
arr_sliced = arr[1:].copy()
```

Comment: My issue is not just to delete the first row. I want to know how can I delete rows from that kind of arrays

Comment: Look at `arr_sliced.shape` shape, you'll find `(2, 3, 3)`. This is exactly as per your desired output. You need to [update and clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52927712/edit) your question if you now decide you need something else.

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks. I hope it is much more understandable now.

Comment: @GunayAbdullayeva, Unfortunately, that doesn't help. Update your **desired output**, which still shows a `(2, 3, 3)` array.

Comment: The initial array shape like (3,3,3) and desired output (2,3,3). I do not need to change anything.